# sql server logging general error as login issue

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2016 dev edition and have one question.

When I tried to "Object Explorer -> Management -> Maintenance Plans -> double click one full backup plan -> double click subplan -> trying to see list of database on selection box" => got an error message in some cases(system said it can't be shown, "This task requires the connection to be initialized").

It's not the problem. Since I guess that list of databases on backup plan, in some cases, has changed from fist time it made and it might cause some problems.

But the real problem is "SQL Server Logs" writes that issues as login error with local machine.

Am I right? I checked it several times but I have no idea why it is login issue.

Looking around some objects on object explorer Using SSMS can cause trouble like that?

Please give me any advice.

I guess there are more errors shown as login issue like that. It confuse me what the real problem is, and how important error it was when I daily check using sp "sp_readerrorlog".

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. It is bug of SQL Server 2016.

Please check two links below.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4486936-fix-login-failed-for-user-error-occurs-when-you-run-maintenance-plan-with-sql-login-account-in-sql-server-f23fd667-78e6-0bd8-d270-5a46747b78dc

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/83b3d647-7c66-4b9b-a63d-bdc2c39385f6/maintenance-plan-login-failed-for-user-sa-on-master-database?forum=sqlsecurity

In my case, backup maintenance plan agent job has executed but SQL Server has logged as login error with SQL Server login user .

solution 1. Update the SQL Server version.
solution 2. Change the maintenance plan connection to Windows NT Integrated security